# I have four tables - Employees, Departments, Jobs, and Salaries. However, Employees and Departments are the only tables with a direct relationship ji

Tags: python, sql

I have four tables - `Employees`, `Departments`, `Jobs`, and `Salaries`. However, `Employees` and `Departments` are the only tables with a direct relationship via a common column (`dept_id`). The other tables (`Jobs` and `Salaries`) do not have any direct common columns with the first two tables. How can I join these tables to retrieve `empno`, `lastname`, `deptname`, `jobdesc`, and `salary`?

Here are the structures of my tables:

- `Employees`:

  - emp_id
  - lastname
  - dept_id
- `Departments`:

  - dept_id
  - deptname
- `Jobs`:

  - job_id
  - jobdesc
- `Salaries`:

  - salary_id
  - emp_id
  - salary_amount

I'm looking to create a query that retrieves the mentioned columns by joining these tables together. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can join `Jobs` since other tables do not have FK referencing `job_id` in `Jobs`.

If only we assume that there's a column in `Employees` (let's call it `job_id`) that references `Jobs` (as this is a common design in such schemas), the query would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    e.emp_id AS empno, 
    e.lastname, 
    d.deptname, 
    j.jobdesc, 
    s.salary_amount AS salary
FROM 
    Employees e
INNER JOIN 
    Departments d ON e.dept_id = d.dept_id
LEFT JOIN 
    Jobs j ON e.job_id = j.job_id
LEFT JOIN 
    Salaries s ON e.emp_id = s.emp_id;
```